# How to retrieve increment data from firebase one by one?

Tags: android, firebase

I have a database, and I want to retrieve name 1 by 1. At first it only shows `Alex`

```
{
  "parent" : {
    "number1" : {
      "info" : "sadsad",
      "name" : "Alex"
    },
    "number2" : {
      "info" : "sadsad",
      "name" : "Andre"
    },
    "number3" : {
      "info" : "sadsad",
      "name" : "Allen"
    }
  }
}
```

When I click `nextButton`, Alex would be replaced by `Andre`, and when I click `prevButton`, `Andre` would be replaced by `Alex`. How to achieve that?

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        root= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        pariant= root.child("parent");
        number = 1;
        pariant.child("number"+number).child("name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                editText.setHint("His name is "+ value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //retrieve the next name here
            }
        });

prevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //retrieve previous name here
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why not load all names from the database, ordered by number, and place them in a list/map to be iterated through?

Comment: @AgiHammerthief, because i only want to display it one by one.

Comment: You have to create sumething like `counter` which you will use in request/method call. And clicking `next` you have to increase by `1`, and for `previous` decrease it.

Comment: Ok thanks, as Boken suggest i tried using this tutorial https://www.viralandroid.com/2015/10/how-to-increase-and-decrease-integer-value-when-the-button-is-clicked.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to introduce counter in this class which you will use in method call.

And clicking `next` you have to increase by 1, and for `previous` button just decrease it.

```
// New counter
private static int counter = 1;

// Your method from the question
public void mainMethod(int number) {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    pariant = root.child("parent");
    number = 1;

    // load data (at the beginning)
    loadName(counter);

    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // increase counter
            counter++;
            // load data
            loadName(counter);
        }
    });

    prevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // To do not load user 0, -1, -2...
            if (counter <= 1) {
                return;
            }

            // decrease counter 
            counter--;
            // load data
            loadName(counter);
        }
    });
}
```

You can extract "loading logic" to new method where you pass number (`counter`) and load data

```
private static void loadName(int number) {
    pariant.child("number" + number).child("name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            editText.setHint("His name is " + value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```